# Ionic/Cordova Remote Debugging

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, ionic-framework

i'm trying to remote debug my application on my android tablet. the strange thing is this works only through chrome/inspect/remote debugging if a chrome browser is running on my tablet.

the application then is able to connect to my server. if no chrome browser is running the application isn't able to connect.

does somebody have an idea?

i also read that the debuggable=true flag must be set in androidManifest.xml. this file is generated through the build process. is there also a possibility to define it in config.xml?

regards angela

Comment: it seems that the debugging works. but the connection to the sever can only be made if a chrome browser is running

Answer (score 0):

Try out another way.

There is a programm which is able to debug your apps in google chrome. It's called GapDebug.
You'll find further information about it here -> [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/)